# Combining multiple Cells into one Row with the row showing all data points.

Tags: excel

I have a range of cells D1-AS(this range changes based on the month) that I would like to combine into one cell.  I would also like this cell to show all the data points without clicking in the cell.  I have looked through several post but nothing I have found has worked. [Cell B6 is what I currently have][2]

Comment: Have you tried the `=CONCATENATE()` function?

Comment: Yea and for some reason I can not get it to work unless I type out each cell.  Like I can not select the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the **CONCATENATE FOR ERIC** function:

> =CONCATENATEFORERIC(D1:AS1)

Code to be inserted before function can be used:

```
Public Function CONCATENATEFORERIC(rng As Range) As String

Dim rng1 As Range

CONCATENATEFORERIC = ""

   For Each rng1 In rng
      CONCATENATEFORERIC = CONCATENATEFORERIC & rng1.Text
   Next rng1

End Function
```

Comment: Clever function name